# Vertica. Count of Null and Not-Null of all columns of a Table

Tags: sql, vertica

How can we get null and non-null counts of all columns of a Table in Vertica? Table can have n number of columns and for each column we need to get count of nulls and non-nulls values of that table.

For Example.
Below Table has two columns

```
column1 Column2
1         abc
          pqr
3
          asd
5
```

If its a specific column then we can check like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where column1 is null;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where column1 is not null;
```

Same query for column2

I checked system tables like projection_storage and others but I cant figure out a generic query which gives details by hard coding only TABLE NAME in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello @user2452689:  Here is a dynamically generated VSQL statement which meets your requirement of counting nulls & not nulls in N columns.  Notice that this writes a temporary SQL file out to your working directory, and then execute it via the \i command.  You only need to change the first two variables per table.  Hope this helps - good luck!  :-D

```
--CHANGE SCHEMA AND TABLE PARAMETERS ONLY:
\set table_schema '\'public\''
\set table_name '\'dim_promotion\''
---------
\o temp_sql_file
\pset tuples_only
select e'select \'' || :table_schema || e'\.' || :table_name || e'\' as table_source' as txt
union all
select * from (
select 
', sum(case when ' || column_name || ' is not null then 1 else 0 end) as ' || column_name || '_NOT_NULL
, sum(case when ' || column_name || ' is null then 1 else 0 end) as ' || column_name || '_NULL' as txt
from columns
where table_schema = :table_schema
and table_name = :table_name
order by ordinal_position
) x
union all
select ' from ' || :table_schema || e'.' || :table_name || ';' as txt ;
\o
\pset tuples_only
\i temp_sql_file
```

Comment: Thanks this was the approach was trying to figure out . Can you please tell me what temp_sql_file will contain.

Comment: I tried by providing the schema and table name. But my temp_sql_file contain only  select abc.table as table_source from abc.table

Comment: The temp_sql_file should contain the complete SQL statement that you will be running ... it will look something like this SQL below.  You run it with the \i command.

 select 'public.TABLE_TEST' as table_source
 , sum(case when COL_01 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as COL_01_NOT_NULL
, sum(case when COL_01 is null then 1 else 0 end) as COL_01_NULL
  from public.TABLE_TEST;

Comment: And if you like this answer, then can you please accept this solution?  ;-)

Comment: @user2452689 -- can you please also check the capitalization in your SQL parameters?  The select statement from the "columns" system table relies on an exact match.  If the table is capitalized differently, this this would explain why you are not getting any records in "temp_sql_file"...

Comment: Thanks Eli Reiman, Now temp_sql_file is generating. But when try to execute with \i command, its considering header (txt) and footer (no of roes) because of which its not executing. How can i force \i command not to include header and footer of tem_sql_file? The generated file is giving the desired output when I execute manually without \i

Comment: @user2452689 -- this behavior of header and footer is related to the command "\pset tuples_only" -- when you first run it, you will turn off the header and footer.  The second time that it runs, it flips those outputs back on.  So just make sure that you run \pset tuples_only, and then run your select statement to generate the SQL file.  (might be that you ran something manually, and it reset the tuples_only behavior).  Play around with it -- good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
select count(*) as cnt,
       count(column1) as cnt_column1,
       count(column2) as cnt_column2
from t;
```

`count()` with a column name or expression counts the number of non-`NULL` values in the column/expression.

(Obviously, the number of `NULL` values is `cnt - cnt_columnX`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  column1_not_null
       ,column2_not_null
       ,column3_not_null

       ,cnt - column1_not_null as column1_null
       ,cnt - column2_not_null as column2_null
       ,cnt - column3_not_null as column3_null


from   (select  count(*)         as cnt

               ,count (column1)  as column1_not_null
               ,count (column2)  as column2_not_null
               ,count (column3)  as column3_not_null

        from    mytable
        ) t
```